# How to make a plugin dll for QT with a library that implements *part* of a pure interface

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I've been refactoring some code for a project that has plugins. The plugin basically implements a (pure virtual) interface.

However, some of the plugins use a substantial amount of shared code, which is currently built as an archive library and linked into each plugin dll. In class form it's something like this:

```
class PluginA : public Common { 
  QOBJECT
  Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "org.me.PluginA" FILE "pluginA.json")
public:
    virtual void Func1() override { do stuff; }
    //virtual void Func2() override implemented in Common
    virtual void Func3() override { Common::Func3(); fiddle() }
};
//pluginB in a different DLL does similar things
```

Then this is in a static library which is linked by pluginA and pluginB

```
class Common : public SomeInterface {
    public:
    //virtual void Func1() override //implemented by plugin
    virtual void Func2 override { magic stuff, probably calling func2; }
    virtual void Func3() override { stuff; }
}
```

And finally the interface which only exists in a header file

```
class Someinterface {
    public:
    virtual void Func1() = 0;
    virtual void Func2() = 0;
    virtual void Func3() = 0;
}
```

Now, as I said, I'd like to make Common a plugin module. If I do that without adding the Q_PLUGIN_METADATA line, nothing gets added as an entry point and the link fails oddly

If I add the Q_PLUGIN_METADATA line, something in QT tries to instantiate an object of class Common, which doesn't work because it doesn't implement all the functions (for instance Func1 which probably returns the name...)

I could I suppose implement a dummy function that threw an exception if it was called, but then that would make it difficult to implement a new PluginC to some extent, as you wouldn't get compile errors for non-implemented functions, you'd get runtime errors.

What approaches can I take? Note that there are other plugins that inherit directly from SomeInterface that don't require / use the common code that pluginA and pluginB make use of.